# AjaxControlToolkit ModelPopupExtender displaying left side of the screen instead of center

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

This is my code for ModelPopupExtender:

```
<asp:View ID="ViewCDB" runat="server">
                    <div id="cdbupbar" style="padding:2px">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCDB" runat="server" CssClass="CButton" 
                            onclick="btnCDB_Click" Text="Create New Discussion Board" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel13" runat="server">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="newButton" />
                            <uc2:CreateNewCDB ID="CreateNewCDB1" runat="server" />
                        </asp:Panel>

                        <asp:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
    targetcontrolid="btnCDB" popupcontrolid="Panel13" CancelControlID="Button9" 
    backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">
</asp:modalpopupextender>
                    </div>
                  </asp:View>
```

The problem is that, whenever I click `btnCDB` button, it shows the model popup but it is displayed on left hand side of the window instead in middle. I tried to add it in `<div>` and `<td>` and assigning their alignment property to "middle" but didn't worked. The container that holding this code is set to left aligned. I can't change it because its website's main container, changing its alignment will cause all website content to middle. That I don't want. Also I checked all CSSes, they didn't effect the alignment property.

Comment: Get away from the AjaxControlToolkit. Use jQuery and jQuery UI and save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: But most of the time they didn't work in IE

Comment: jQuery didn't work in IE? What version were you using?

Comment: I tried many JQuery examples on it. But none of them gave expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel13" runat="server" style="margin-left:35%;">
```

try this and if it makes any difference, u better define a css class for your panel.

Comment: thanks @Emre this worked. I changed the value to 15% instead and its all good now. Starter +1 and answer accept to you from me :)